# Why is the "opposite category" operation a functor?

Tags: category-theory

I have seen some question in this site saying that the "opposite category" opration is a functor. But from the definition of a functor, we require $F(g\circ f)=F(g)\circ F(f)$. What I feel confused about is that for $f: A\to B, g: B\to C,\;$ $F(f)$ is from $B$ to $A$ and $F(g)$ is from $C$ to $B$ so we cannot compose them as $F(g)\circ F(f)$. So why does this operation satisfy the definition of a functor? Am I misunderstanding something?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is a "contravariant functor" which requires that $F(g\circ f) = F(f)\circ F(g)$, $F(\mathrm{id}_x)=\mathrm{id}_{F(x)}$, and that if $f: x \to y$ is an arrow then $F(f):F(y) \to F(x)$. The functors which preserve the direction of arrows are sometimes called "covariant functors". Note that if $F: C \to D$ is a contravariant functor, then this can be thought of as the covariant functor $F: C^\mathrm{op} \to D$.

Comment: The composition law you put if only for covariant functors, you can also have contravariant functors which reverse domain and codomain. An important example is the singular cohomology functor.

Comment: There are two things you could mean by "the opposite category functor:" 1) The functor $\operatorname{Cat} \to \operatorname{Cat}$ sending any category to its opposite category, and 2) For a given category $C$, the ("contravariant") functor $C \to C^{\operatorname{op}}$ that sends objects and morphisms to themselves. From the problem you're having, it sounds like you're talking about (2), but by itself "the opposite category operation" sounds much more like (1). Can you clarify which operation you're talking about?

Comment: @MikeHaskel I am talking about 1). I mean that sending objects of a category to themselves, and send the morphisms to the ones that goes in an opposite direction.

Comment: @Hayden So could you please clarify that if the definition that I mentioned above is the definition of a **covarient functors** only, not a precise definition of all functors?

Comment: Yes, that's the definition only for covariant functors.

Comment: @NoahRiggenbach Oh I see, thank you for your example!

Comment: It solves my question. Thanks for all of you who leaves comments above!

Comment: Note that meaning 1 in @MikeHaskel's comment is a covariant functor from Cat to Cat. It sends any functor $f:C\to D$ to the functor $f:C^{op}\to D^{op}$ that literally is just $f$.  The earlier comments about contravariance assumed meaning 2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm afraid I don't really understand what you're trying to say is a problem; I think you are somehow confused about what it means to say that the opposite functor operation is a functor.  Let me just walk through how that works.

To avoid some confusion, let me fix some notation.  If $\mathcal{C}$ is a category, we write $\mathcal{C}^{op}$ for its opposite category.  If $X$ is an object of $\mathcal{C}$, we write $X^o$ for $X$ considered as an object of $\mathcal{C}^{op}$.  If $f:X\to Y$ is a morphism of $\mathcal{C}$, we write $f^o:Y^o\to X^o$ for the corresponding morphism of $\mathcal{C}^{op}$.

The claim now is that there is a functor $T:\mathtt{Cat}\to\mathtt{Cat}$ which on objects is given by $T(\mathcal{C})=\mathcal{C}^{op}$ for each category $\mathcal{C}$.  To verify this, we need to specify what $T$ does on morphisms: that is, if $F:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ is a functor, we need to define a functor $T(F):\mathcal{C}^{op}\to\mathcal{D}^{op}$.  The definition is simple: on objects we define $T(F)(X^o)=F(X)^o$ and on morphisms we define $T(F)(f^o)=F(f)^o$.

Let's check that this $T(F)$ really is a functor. If $f^o:Y^o\to X^o$ is a morphism of $\mathcal{C}^{op}$, then $f:X\to Y$ in $\mathcal{C}$, so $F(f):F(X)\to F(Y)$ and $F(f)^o:F(Y)^o\to F(X)^o$.  That is, $T(F)(f^o)=F(f)^o$ is indeed a morphism from $T(F)(Y^o)=F(Y)^o$ to $T(F)(X^o)=F(X)^o$.

We can also check that $T(F)$ preserves identities and composition.  For identities, we have $$T(F)(1_{X^o})=T(F)(1_X^o)=F(1_X)^o=1_{F(X)}^o=1_{F(X)^o}.$$ For composition, suppose $f^o:Y^o\to X^o$ and $g^o:Z^o\to Y^o$ are two composable morphisms in $\mathcal{C}^{op}$.  Then $$T(F)(f^og^o)=T(F)((gf)^o)=F(gf)^o=(F(g)F(f))^o=F(f)^oF(g)^o=T(F)(f^o)T(F)(g^o).$$  Here we use the fact that composition in the opposite category is defined by $f^og^o=(gf)^o$.

So, for any functor $F:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$, we have defined a functor $T(F):\mathcal{C}^{op}\to\mathcal{D}^{op}$.  The only thing that remains to be checked is that this operation $T$ preserves identities and composition of functors: $T(1_{\mathcal{C}})=1_{\mathcal{C}^{op}}$ and $T(FG)=T(F)T(G)$ if $F:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ and $G:\mathcal{B}\to\mathcal{C}$ are functors.  This is tedious but straightforward to check and does not appear to be your point of confusion so I will omit the details.

Comment: It takes me some time to read it and understand it and it is far more than I expect. I admit that I mixed something up and misunderstand the construction but now it is cleaer to me. This answer is so helpful! and useful to me! Thanks a lot.